# Catch document changed or auto-saved event in Google Docs

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to build a Google Docs Add-on that should highlight some words in the document based on input in the add-on's sidebar.
I managed to do that on user interaction (click of a button in the sidebar). The problem is that I also need to do the same as the document is changed: while the user is typing, or at least when it's auto-saved

Can anyone suggest any documentation I should read that would help me achieve that?

Google App Script's onEdit trigger is available for Spreadsheets only.

Comment: Best way to start learning is through the official docs available online. Check [Document Service documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/) if the function you are trying will be feasible.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I looked at the DocumentService API, but that won't help me, because that's an API available on the server side. I am looking for a way to catch that event in the browser (client-side through Javascript)